# Is it faster to 'check for inequality and set' or just 'directly set' variables

Tags: variables, optimization

Which one is faster:

```
if (someValue != otherValue) someValue = otherValue;
```

or

```
someValue = otherValue;
```

Or will they be optimized into the same code?

Comment: Just use whichever form expresses your intention more clearly and don't worry about (premature) optimisation. You can profile and optimise any bottlenecks later if necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a case of micro-optimization (see [Jeff Atwood's 2005 post](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/01/micro-optimization-and-meatballs.html) on the subject). If you're actually worrying about which to use in a project, don't. There's a **very high chance that it just doesn't matter at all**.

However, if you're instead interested in understanding why there might be a difference underneath the hood, keep reading.

Whether or not there's a speed difference (and even which one might be better in terms of overall performance) depends on factors including the data type of the variable(s), the programming language, and the users' system architectures.

In C++ using `int`s, your "directly set" snippet will be faster than your "check and set" snippet in the vast majority of cases. This is because the compare and branch (or compare and conditional move, or equivalent) that are executed when the values are equal will actually be slower than the (unneeded) move that would have been executed. However, the difference is so small that you'd have to do this many times before it made a difference. Furthermore, an optimizing compiler will probably remove the dead code for you.

There are possible exceptions, of course. One potential case is a cache-coherent multiprocessor system where writes cause other processors to invalidate their cache lines even when the value doesn't change (I'm not sure how often this is the case, but it seems at least possible). Then, it may be better to do the check first if the variable is read often but changed infrequently (that is, the code runs many times, but it's usually the case that `someValue == otherValue`). Similarly, in a memory-bound program, it might make sense to do the check if your cache always flushes to memory (for a write-through cache) or sets the dirty bit (for a write-back cache) on a write even if the value hasn't changed (again, sounds plausible).

If `someValue` and `otherValue` are more complex types where comparison and/or assignment have been overridden, the two given pieces of code may not even be equivalent, to say nothing of the performance.

Answer (score 0):

In the codebase I'm using, most of the object setters, have something like:

```
void SetSomeValue(T otherValue)
{
    if(someValue!=otherValue)
    {
       cout << "Somevalue has changed from " << someValue << " to " << othervalue << endl;
       someValue=otherValue;
    }
}
```

Which makes non-development debugging easier.  (Yes it puts loads of text in the log, but we can turn on or off the logging with runtime switches, this is just an example).